# Change random Elements in DOM (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to write a js for any simple html side. The js should pick all img or p elements for example and swap the position of 2 random elements of the same type by clicking a button.

```
let max = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
let min = 0;
let x1 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
let x2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
let tmp1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[x1];
let tmp2 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[x2];
```

thats my first steps but i dont know how to go on. hope someone can help

Comment: I would recomment to use jquery not because of the simpliness, but because it is crossplatform, but the javascript you should write separate rules for different browsers and versions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `insertBefore` to do this.

```js
let max = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
let min = 0;
let x1 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
let x2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
let tmp1 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[x1];
let tmp2 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[x2];

// from here, do the changes
let wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"); // get wrapper reference
wrapper.insertBefore(tmp1, tmp2); // insert node before tmp1.
wrapper.insertBefore(tmp2, tmp1);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
</div>
```

Things to be noticed here,

1. All the items you need to change position, should be under some node. Instead of directly having them under `document` I've created a wrapper node and added it.
2. Just to make it bit easier for viewing, I've added the nodes as `div` not `img`. But code should work just the same.
3. This is just to demonstrate `insertBefore`. For proper implementation, you need to check for `nextSibling` or `previousSibling` and do it with those nodes.